# Timer Control in C# windows Form

Tags: c#, timer, windows-forms-designer

I am using onkeyPress event and a timer to execute a method. I have a textbox, i want allow user to type their server name in the text box. Traditionally events fires on every key press, but i put my method in timer elapsed events and want the timer to fire the action only when the user wait for five seconds. Below is my timer.

```
      private void tbServer_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
      {
          //atimer.Stop();
          atimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
          atimer.Interval = 5000;
          atimer.AutoReset = false;
          if (atimer.Enabled)
          {
              return;
          }
          else
          {
              atimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
              atimer.Enabled = true;
          }
      }
```

From the above, I want my timer to fire the elapsed event only if another instance of the timer is not running (i.e ignore any key press before the five seconds interval of timer). I stop my timer after execution complete in the elapsed timer event below

```
     private void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (ping(tbServer.Text, 1))
         {
             string txt = "Server Matched";
             SetText(txt, true);
             atimer.Enabled = false;
         }
         else
         {
              string txt = " Invalid Server Address";
              SetText(txt, false);
              atimer.Enabled = false;
          }
      }
```

The above code rises the timer elapsed event for each key type regardless of the condition. How do I make it ignore the keys type when user did not leave a 5 seconds interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are making a new Timer instance on every click which is fired after 5 seconds. The other timers would stop if you disable/dispose already existing timers.

```
  if (atimer != null)
  {
      atimer.Stop();
      atimer.Dispose();
      atimer = null;
  }

  atimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
  atimer.Interval = 5000;
  atimer.AutoReset = false;
  if (atimer.Enabled)
  {
      return;
  }
  else
  {
      atimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
      atimer.Enabled = true;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you make a new timer every keypress,

you need to check aTimer before assigning a new timer to it.

```
if(aTimer == null) 
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    atimer.Interval = 5000;
    atimer.AutoReset = false;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Keith for the fast reply. I apply what you said as follows.I realized when a user type 10 characters without waiting for 5 seco ranges. It fires like three times, instead of the ten times it does before. What i did was to add my if/else above below your code. And also add else to ur if and execute my if/else again.